# How to embed a Python interpreter on a website

Tags: python, web-applications, interpreter

I am attempting to build an educational coding site, similar to [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com), but I am frankly at a loss as to what steps should be taken. Could I be pointed in the right direction in including even a simple python interpreter in a webapp?

Comment: You can see how it works in ipython's notebook: sudo apt-get install ipython ipython notebook

Comment: I'm not the most experienced with web development tools. I'm hoping to learn as much as I can from a project with an ambitious goal!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html

Comment: Oh, this will be pretty helpful. The [IPython Notebook site](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) even offers a how-to on running a public notebook server!

Comment: Thanks alot, @ChristopheD. I'll read through it.

Comment: Hey men. I'm struggeling with this problem too. did you find a way to make it work? please let me know if you did. It's really important!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option might be to use PyPy to create a sandboxed python. It would limit the external operations someone could do.

Once you have that set up, your website would take the code source, send it over ajax to your webserver, and the server would run the code in a subprocess of a sandboxed python instance. You would also be able to kill the process if it took longer than say 5 seconds. Then you return the output back as a response to the client.

See these links for help on a PyPy sandbox:
http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html
http://readevalprint.com/blog/python-sandbox-with-pypy.html

To create a fully interactive REPL would be even more involved. You would need to keep an interpreter alive to each client on your server. Then accept ajax "lines" of input and run them through the interp by communicating with the running process, and return the output.

Overall, not trivial. You would need some strong dev skills to do this comfortably.  You may find this task a bit daunting if you are just learning.

Comment: Thanks for outlining the steps that I'll have to take. I figured that a project like this might be tough. I'm grateful that you took the time to show me the ropes!

Answer (score 7):

There's more to do here than you think.

The major problem is that you *cannot* let people run arbitrary Python code on your webserver. For example, what happens if they do

```
import os
os.system("rm -rf *.*")
```

So clearly you have to run this Python code securely. But *then* you have the problem of securing Python, which is basically impossible because of how dynamic it is. And so you'll probably have to run the Python shell in a virtual machine, which comes with its own headaches.

---

Have you seen e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/downloads/detail?name=shell_20091112.tar.gz&can=2&q=?

Comment: Going through some searches, I was aware of some of the security issues involved in allowing arbitrary code. Thanks for showing me an actual example though, it clarified quite a bit for me!

I'll be going over the AJAX shell you linked to trying to figure out how it was implemented. I appreciate you showing it to me.

Answer (score 7):

One recent option for this is to use [repl](http://repl.it/languages).

This option is awesome because the compilers **are made using JavaScript** so the **compilation** and **execution** is made in the **user-side**, meaning that the server is free of vulnerabilities.

They have compilers for: *Python3, Python, Javascript, Java, Ruby, PHP*...

I strongly recommend you to check their site at http://repl.it

Answer (score 2):

Look into LXC Containers. They have a pretty cool api that you can use to create lightweight linux containers. You could run the subprocess commands inside that container that way the end user could not mess with your main server.