# How can I check the output of a Python script on a PHP website?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html

I'm making a website in PHP for a schoolproject of mine. In this project I want to make a sort of Quiz about pieces of Python code, like the test you get when taking a online course for programming. I need my PHP website to do three things:

1. The user needs to be able to type Python code in a on-page
   editor/IDE.
2. The output from that Python script needs to be checked and I want to
   be able to use an If-function in PHP to tell the user if the output
   is correct.
3. If something was wrong I need to be able to echo the output from the
   Python console with PHP onto the website.

I know the basics of both these languages but this is something I can't figure out.
Can someone help me out here?
Thanks in advance!

Ivan

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: [how to embed a python interpreter on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264918/how-to-embed-a-python-interpreter-on-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

well,

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

1. you can use a shell_exec() function of php to
2. run you python script,
3. and get back your output;
4. then you can print it on you php file.

Comment: Hello, So basicly I need to make a input field in HTMl so the user can make type some Python code in it, then I need to place the text into a .py file with PHP en then I can use this command in PHP to display it on a website, is that correct?